# cannot able to access the variable from parent constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi friends I'm new to CodeIgniter, I've downloaded version 3.04 and in controller page i've created parent constructor .

Controller :

```
class Vote extends CI_Controller {
public function construct(){
parent::__construct();
$this->data['theme'] = 'admin';        
}
public function index()
{        
$this->data['page'] = 'login_page';
$this->load->vars($this->data);
$this->load->view($this->data['theme'].'/template');
}
```

**Error :**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: theme
>
> Filename: controllers/vote.php
>
> Line Number: 30
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\poll\application\controllers\vote.php Line: 30
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\poll\index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once

Why do I get an error like this I have added $autoload['helper'] = array('url'); also.

Comment: change this `$this->load->view($this->data['theme'].'/template');` to `$this->load->view($this->data.'/template');` and try

Comment: @PathikVejani :A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: controllers/Vote.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a file called `MY_Controller.php` under `application/core` folder. In this file, you should create a class. E.g:

```
class Some_class extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->data['theme'] = 'admin';
 }
}
```

Than edit your Controller like below:

```
class Vote extends Some_class {
public function construct(){
parent::__construct();
}
public function index()
{        
$this->data['page'] = 'login_page';
$this->load->vars($this->data);
$this->load->view($this->data['theme'].'/template');
}
```